# Evaluation and feedback using Optical Mark Recognition systems in secondary school

Tags: secondary-education, course-design, technology-in-education, assessment, interactive-teaching

## OMR in exit tickets

I plan to use an
[OMR, Optical Mark Recognition systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_mark_recognition) at the end of (some of) my classes.
I want to use the same OMR system for exit tickets scattered over the academic year (not necessarily on exiting **every** class).

At present I am looking into [SDAPS](https://sdaps.org/) for building the forms in LaTEX and for registerering the printed, hand-filled-in forms. There are other OMS systems, though, supporting automated registering of marked paper forms.

### Teacher making the marks - student answering open questions

My plan is to provide open questions and white space in order for the
**student to answer in writing (and drawing)**,
while the fields preprinted for marking are reserved for the teacher's
feedback.
[image: Draft form]
Here, of course the white space for answer may need to be enlarged.
Cosider the above screendump as a draft.

### Why?

By training handwriting for assessment, I want to take the
tool (Maple, TI-NSpire, ...)
out of the solution
and inviting the student to focus on the theory,
the mathematical principles.

By posing the question and collecting responses,
I want to tell the class as a group of students
why focus is where it is in the next session.

By registering the marks,
I want the student to feel recognized.

### - But how?

Would OMR be the way for me to go towards my objective of
giving fast and visible feedback to students
and registering individual levels of skills for
guidance (and assessment)?
Or would some other way be far more obvious?

Having experience with using LaTEX packages
such as `tasks` and `exsheets`,
what would be a good choice for me implementing an OMR?
**Which OMR** would you recommend, why?

What is considered good practice regarding
such questionnaires?
I mean regarding
the **language** (including use of mathematical notation and diagrams)
in questions,
and in the **requested answers** indicated by the form layout?

Comment: Could you explain how OMR (i.e. the test form in the Wikipedia link you gave), where students just mark the right answer and don't give any explanation or proof works together with "training handwriting" and "focus on theory"?

Comment: @dirk: Certainly, I edited my question to accomodte your clarifying question.

Comment: You didn't say whether this was copied from an actual question, but if so, a bit more care should be taken with the wording, as there are grammar mistakes, awkward wording, and even a misspelled word that a basic spell-check would catch. *(moments later)* OK, I see now you wrote "Cosider the above screendump as a draft". But besides what I already mentioned, notice that "you need approximately" is not what you want to say (some students will take less time), but rather "you have approximately" (or some such).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wish to take a look at some online grading applications:

GradeCam    -   https://gradecam.com/

AKINDI      --      https://akindi.com/

Exam Reader --  https://bebyaz.com/ExamReader

All In Learning  -  http://www.allinlearning.com/scanning/

FlashGrade  -    https://www.flashgrade.com/

Gradescope  -   https://gradescope.com/

QuickKey    -   https://get.quickkeyapp.com/

ZipGrade    -   https://www.zipgrade.com/

Comment: These look fantastic. I look forward to investigating them further. Do you know if any of them have free options?

Comment: GradeCam $15 per month (ouch!) 2-minute overview video  https://vimeo.com/194585858   

Mastery Connect   https://masteryconnect.com/   
Free for verified teachers; Up to 10 questions per quiz

AKINDI    https://akindi.com/ 
Free: for K-12, one assessment at a time;
Teacher: $99, Unlimited assessments

QuickKey - https://get.quickkeyapp.com/ -
Free for trial: grade up to 100 papers per month;
QuickKey Pro for Teachers: $30/teacher-year;

ZipGrade - https://www.zipgrade.com/
Free for teachers: scan up to 100 papers per month.
Paid for teachers: $8/teacher-year;